# How to use VOLTTRON with PiCAN2(CanBUS)?

Tags: volttron

I learned that volttron supports with Raspberry Pi.
In my project, i'm gonna implement agent in raspberry and use Pican2 (Canbus) to get information from DSP.
So it's possible or not to write CANBUS in volttron's agent?
Or it has another ways?

Please kindly give me some instruction!!!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to write an Agent that can communicate with the PiCAN2 as it does provide a Python interface via SocketCAN.

What you probably want to do is create an MasterDriver interface that uses the PiCAN2 Python interface. Ideally this interface would be configured in a similar manner as the other interfaces.

A high level explanation of interfaces is found here: http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/devguides/agent_development/Develop-Driver-Agent.html

More detailed documentation on interface creation is found here: http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/apidocs/services/MasterDriverAgent/master_driver.interfaces.html#creating-a-new-interface

Comment: Does it has any example to use volttron with device beside BACnet and Modbus?